# WCF Channel в Faulted state

Tags: c#, wcf

Создал `Reference` c внешнего сервиса, создаю клиента

```
using( var c = new ExternalService() )
{
    c.DoSomething();
}
```

Сразу после создания до вызова метода `DoSomething()` `Channel` находится в состоянии `Faulted` (обычно `Сreated`). Методом проб ошибок обнаружил, что проблема связана с тем что метод `DoSomething` возвращает комплексный тип у которого установлен атрибут `MessageContract`. Но не понятно что конкретно не нравится.

Как можно диагностировать проблему и более детально получить описание ошибки?

Пробовал подключать `svclog`. Там есть ошибка создания канала, но детальной информации о причинах не отображается. Что еще можно попробовать?

Comment: в какой момент канал переходит в `Faulted`? после вызова `DoSomething`? или сразу после создания?

Comment: @PashaPash написано, что сразу после создания.

Comment: @andreycha и там же написано "обычно `Created`", что как бы совсем не `Faulted`. Если канал падает на клиенте - то это можно просто отладить со снятой галкой Just My Code. А так - это просьба помочь в отладке без минимально воспроизводимого примера. И даже без текста ошибки.

Comment: Да состояние Fauted сразу из конструктора выходит, до каких либо вызовов. Обычно Created имеется ввиду что в других прокси-классах после вызова конструктора состояние Created. После экспериментов оказалось что влияет в основном аттрибут XmlSerializerFormat у метода DoSomething() генерится оно автоматом из wsdl  пока не понятно в чем причина чем этот аттрибут так не нравится. Есть ли какой-то способ получить более детальную ошибку понять что именно не нравится ?

Comment: А клиента разве не так создавать: `var client = new ExternalServiceClient(); ... client.Close();`?